# iframe src with .appcache fallback

Tags: html, iframe, manifest

Html code:

```
<iframe src='online.html'></iframe>
<script src='online.js'></script>
```

manifest file:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
#VER
CACHE:

FALLBACK:
online.html offline.html
online.js offline.js

NETWORK:
*
```

Problem:
When My Borwser is offline, it can auto load offline.js replace online.js, but always load online.html not offline.html.

What i should do?

Comment: Better provide environment details which your browser is running

Comment: environment is Chrome 20.0.1132.57 in Ubuntu 12.04 x64

Answer (score 0):

write iframe in your js file.

online.js

```js
document.write('<iframe src="online.html"></iframe>');
```

offline.js

```js
document.write('<iframe src="offline.html"></iframe>');
```